Issue with Partial Views in RazorLight using Component.InvokeAsync
I am working on a HostApplicationBuilder project to develop a newsletter service where the HTML is built using Mjml in .NET (specifically with Mjml.Net). Previously, the newsletter HTML was constructed with StringBuilder, but I am refactoring it to be built using RazorLight and Mjml.Net.
I have successfully rendered Razor pages and processed them through MJML for a single template. Here's an example:
public async Task<string> RenderRazorMjmlModelAsync(NewsletterDataDto newsletterData, string language, bool hasAlerts)
{
    string? mjmlContent;
    if (hasAlerts)
    {
        mjmlContent = await _razorLightEngine.CompileRenderAsync($"template-alerts-{language}.mjml.cshtml", newsletterData);
    }
    else
    {
        mjmlContent = await _razorLightEngine.CompileRenderAsync($"template-no-alerts-{language}.mjml.cshtml", newsletterData);
    }

    var renderer = new MjmlRenderer();

    var (result, errors) = renderer.Render(mjmlContent);
    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Errors rendering MJML: {Errors}", string.Join(", ", errors));
        return string.Join(", ", errors);
    }

    return result;
}

called from here:
private async Task<bool> SendNewsletterEmail(NewsletterDataDto newsletterDto, string language, List<string> addresses)
{
    string? mail;
    if (newsletterDto.MaxAlerts.Count != 0)
    {
        mail = await _mjmlHelper.RenderRazorMjmlModelAsync(newsletterDto, language, true);        
    }
    else
    {
        mail = await _mjmlHelper.RenderRazorMjmlModelAsync(newsletterDto, language, false);        
    }
    ...
}

And also I've modified the .csproj file adding these lines:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
  <PropertyGroup>
     ...
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Email\NewsletterRazor\**\*.cshtml" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
</Project>

Issue:
The issue arises when I attempt to insert partial views into the main template. I tried adding a partial view using Component.InvokeAsync, as shown below:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper Component
@using NewsletterService.Helper
@using NewsletterService.Dto.Model.Notification
@model NewsletterService.Dto.Model.Notification.NewsletterDataDto

...

@{
   var todayPills = @product.Alerts.Where(alert => alert.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).ToList();
}                                                
<table style='width:100%;'>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
           @await Component.InvokeAsync("DayPills", new
              {
                AlertPills = todayPills,
                Day = "Today"
               })
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

Here's the code of the partial view
@model NewsletterService.Dto.Model.Notification.DayPillsDto

@using NewsletterService.Helper

<table style='width:100%;'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='24' style='font-size: 15px;'>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='day'>
                            <div>
                                <strong>@Model.Day</strong>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var pill in Model.AlertPills)
        {

            <td style='width: @(100.0 / Model.AlertPills.Count)%; padding: 0.07em;'>
                <div style='
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    display: inline-block;
                    border-radius: @(Model.AlertPills.Count >= 24 ? "0.3em" : "20px");
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 15px;
                    background-color: @ColorHelper.AdjustLightness(pill.AlertColor, 5.0)'>
                </div>
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @{
            bool isFirst = true;
        }
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AlertPills.Count; i++)
        {
            var pill = Model.AlertPills[i];
            if (Model.AlertPills.Count < 24 || (Model.AlertPills.Count >= 24 && i % 6 == 0))
            {
                <td colspan='@(Model.AlertPills.Count >= 24 && i % 6 == 0 ? 6 : 1)'>
                    <span align='left' style='color:#7D7D7D; @(isFirst ? "font-weight: bold;" : "")'>
                        @(isFirst ? $"{pill.Date.Hour}h" : $"{pill.Date.Hour}")
                    </span>
                </td>
                isFirst = false;
            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>

However, when running the solution, I get the following exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
This error occurs at the line @await Component.InvokeAsync.
Question: Is there something I'm missing when trying to invoke a partial view using Component.InvokeAsync? Does anyone know how to properly integrate partial views in this context with Razor and MJML.Net?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Hi @wetsbou, when do you call this RenderRazorMjmlModelAsync method? Also pls share your partial view and main page.

Hi @Rena, I've just added some lines of code such as where RenderRazorMjmlmodelAsync is called, the .csproj file and the partial view
